# What's the proper way to update a child reference on a managed entity with ModelMapper?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, entity, dto, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper to map DTOs to database entities through a REST/API Spring micro service and running into an issue when updating the reference to a child entity.  In my service implementation I first get the entity using JPA/Hibernate which is adding it to the persistence context.  The child property is being fetched eagerly so the entire entity object is attached.  Once I have the entity, I'm updating it with the DTO using ModelMapper.  I have a ModelMapper configuration which defines the mapping of the id on the DTO to the id on the child entity.  The initial create works fine, but if a child entity is already associated to the parent and I attempt to update the id, Hibernate complains rightly so that I'm altering the identifier of an instance.  I only care about the reference, I'm not updating any data on the Dormitory entity through this update.

These aren't the exact entities I'm working with, but trying to illustrate with these.  Say I have a Student entity that has a dormitory associated to it.  In the database it Student #123 has Dormitory #456 associated to it.  My incoming DTO changes that association to Dormitory #789.

```
public class Student {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
  private Long studentID;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "DORMITORY_ID")
  private Dormitory dormitory;

  ... getters and setters
}

public class Dormitory {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "DORMITORY_ID")
  private Long dormitoryID;

  @Column(name = "DORMITORY_NAME")
  private String dormitoryName;

  ... getters and setters
}

public class StudentDTO {
  private Long studentID;
  private Long dormitoryID;

  ... getters and setters
}



public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
 
  @Autowired
  private StudentRepository studentRepo;

  @Autowired
  ModelMapper modelMapper;

  public void updateStudent(StudentDTO studentDTO) {
    Student studentToUpdate = studentRepo.findById(studentDTO.getStudentID());
    studentToUpdate.setDormitory(null);  // Doing this works but doesn't seem right.
    modelMapper.map(studentDTO, student)
    studentRepo.saveAndFlush(student);
  }

}

public class ModelMapperConfig {

  @Bean
  public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setDeepCopyEnabled(true);
  
    PropertyMap<StudentDTO, Student> map = new PropertyMap<StudentDTO, Student>() {
      protected void configure() {
        map(source.getDormitoryID(), destination.getDormitory().getDormitoryID());
      }
    };
    modelMapper.addMappings(map)

  }
}
```

If I null out the child entity on the parent before mapping the DTO, it works fine since a new entity is then created through ModelMapper.  This doesn't seem like right approach though and figured I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about ModelMapper, but from what you described, a simple Java Bean mapper is simply not enough for your use case. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. You can then fetch data or flush it back, based on that mapping, and the library takes care of the details of how to flush this in the most efficient way.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface StudentDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getStudentID();
    DormitoryDto getDormitory();
    void setDormitory(DormitoryDto dormitory);
    default void setDormitoryId(Long dormitoryId) {
        setDormitory(evm().getReference(DormitoryDto.class, dormitoryId));
    }

    // Special method to access context
    EntityViewManager evm();

    @EntityView(Dormitory.class)
    @UpdatableEntityView
    interface DormitoryDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getDormitoryID();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`StudentDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, StudentDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<StudentDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

and also allows you to simply flush the data

```
void save(StudentDto student);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!